# Autocorrect / insert textblock by hotkey

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I want to insert a default block of text when hitting a hotkey or when entering a special string  in Visual Studio 2010 (either way would be fine).

Is there a fast and easy way to achieve this?
(Preferably without the use of third party extensions. )

**Background / further explanation:**

I want to use a special trigger-word to insert a default doxygen-commentblock, like "///" or "'''" for XML-commentblocks.
Other than the XML-functionality my inserted text does not have to be intelligent, it would suffice to just insert a default textblock.

My suggested trigger-string would be "---" as it would not collide with any program language I know. My suggested hotkey would be Alt+V.

Thanks for the help
Janis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write your own [Code Snippet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Code snippets are small blocks of reusable code that can be inserted in a code file using a context menu command or a combination of hotkeys. They typically contain commonly-used code blocks such as try-finally or if-else blocks, but they can be used to insert entire classes or methods.

Snippets are simply XML files that contain instructions to the Code Editor. For instance, here's the one that VS 2012 supplies for the C# `if` snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>if</Title>
            <Shortcut>if</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet for if statement</Description>
            <Author>Microsoft Corporation</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
                <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>expression</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Expression to evaluate</ToolTip>
                    <Default>true</Default>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[if ($expression$)
    {
        $selected$ $end$
    }]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

You add new snippets to the IDE using the **Code Snippet Manager**, available from the **Tools** menu item from the main menu.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the answer and sorry for the belated reaction to it.